# Contacts associated with account are not appearing in PageBlockTable

Tags: apex, visualforce, query

I am trying to show contacts associated with account, on selection of account in picklist contacts should come in pageblock table

**Page**

```
<apex:page controller="MyController">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageblock >
            <apex:pageblockSection >
                    <apex:selectList value="{!selectedAccId}" size="1">
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!AccountNameList}"/>
                    </apex:selectList>
            </apex:pageblockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom" >
      <apex:commandButton action="{!showcontact}"  value="Submit"/>
     </apex:pageBlockButtons>
     <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Conlist}" var="tuple">
      <apex:column value="{!tuple.name}" headerValue="Name"/>
      <apex:column value="{!tuple.title}" headerValue="Title"/>
      <apex:column value="{!tuple.email}" headerValue="Email"/>
      <apex:column value="{!tuple.phone}" headerValue="Phone"/> 

      </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
Public class MyController{

    public string SelectedAccId{get;set;}
    public list<contact> Conlist{get;set;}

    Public account acc;

    public list<selectoption> getAccountNameList(){
        List<SelectOption> optionAcc = new List<SelectOption>();      
        optionAcc.add(new selectoption('','--Select--'));
        for(account acc:[SELECT id,name from Account]){
            optionAcc.add(new selectoption(acc.id,acc.name));
        }
        return optionAcc;
       } 

       public pagereference showContact(){
           conlist=[select id,name,email,title,phone from contact where AccountID=:acc.id];    
           return null;
       }

}
```

Comment: Are you getting a particular error? Please describe the problem you're facing.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add a `rerender` attribute to your `<apex:commandButton>`. You probably need to add an `id` attribute to one of your other tags as well. Probably the top level `<apex:pageBlock>` tag.

```
<apex:pageBlock id="content">
    <!-- intermediate markup -->

    <apex:commandButton rerender="content" action="{!showcontact}"  value="Submit" />

    <!-- intermediate markup -->
</apex:pageblock>
```

See also: [Implementing Partial Page Updates with Command Links and Buttons](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_ajax_partial_page_updates.htm?search_text=rerender)